# 10A 5v Relay control Submersible (Water motor)

Tags: motor, relay

Is it possible to control Submersible (Water motor) with 5v 10A relay. Here is the details of the Submersible water motor.

My mains voltage is 225V to 250V

[image]

[image]

If this won't work then what relay should I plan to use here. Any good relay you can suggest.

Comment: "Is it possible" yes it is. Maybe ask a more profound question?

Comment: I am trying to understand what are the things possible to control with this. As this is mentioning 4-10A and 8-20A so I was not sure. Which one will be more suitable, a relay with 10A or 30A as I have both of them.